# Accessing MJPEG Stream .net core

Tags: .net-core, aforge, mjpeg

I am trying to access a mjpeg stream through my .net core app. It seems AForge.Video is not compatible with .net core.
Is there any lib / coding example available how to access a video stream and get single images out of it? Is there any possibility to get Aforge running with .NET core?

```
private MJPEGStream stream = null;

        public void initRecorder(RecorderUnit unit)
        {
            stream = new MJPEGStream(unit.getAdress());
            stream.NewFrame += stream_newFrame;
            stream.VideoSourceError += stream_error;
        }
        private void stream_newFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        }
        private void stream_error(object sender, VideoSourceErrorEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
        }
```

Comment: [AForge hasn't been updated since 2013](https://code.google.com/archive/p/aforge/downloads) - I think you should use a different library entirely. That said, the .NET platform (be it .NET Core or the Windows .NET Framework) never really got popular for doing image-processing work - have you considered writing in a different platform which is more-suited to this kind of workload instead (e.g. C/C++ with libavcodec or Python with OpenCV?)

Comment: I'm sure the original problem was down to the System.Drawing library not being available in NetCore. I'm also pretty sure that this has been solved in later versions of Net Core - which NetCore version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I've had good success using FFmpeg wrappers in C# in times gone by. Here is one that I've used: https://github.com/Ruslan-B/FFmpeg.AutoGen . It takes some work to master the FFmpeg compilation process, which is typically done via cross-compile from Linux, and is typically a necessary part of this. It also takes some work to understand the FFmpeg API. There are a lot of options and steps to extracting frames, and some difficulties in making it performant, especially the display of the extract frames. This project won't be as easy as you were hoping; however, you will have the full FFmpeg power at your fingertips when done.